# Why am I getting this conversion error when I pass a vector by const reference?

Tags: c++, vector, types

Here's a short program that prints out the terms of a `std::vector` object.  The vector itself is passed in as a `const` reference for efficiency.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::vector;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

void print_all_terms(const std::vector<int>&);

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> sequence_1(4, 100);

  print_all_terms(sequence_1);

  return(0);
}

void print_all_terms(const std::vector<int>& sequence)
{
  for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = sequence.begin() ;
       it != sequence.end() ;
       ++it) {
    std::cout << *it << " ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

However, when I run the program, I get an error:

```
error: conversion from '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >' to non-scalar type '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >' requested
```

This is caused by the fact that the iterator `it` is declared as a `std::vector<int>::iterator`, which resolves to

```
__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >
```

while the `begin()` function is returning an object of type

```
__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >
```

The only difference is the `const` in the second one.  But I don't see why that `const` should be there - yes, the variable `sequence` is passed in as a constant reference, but it's the reference that is a `const`, not the sequence itself.

Comment: when calling [begin()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/begin) on a const vector you get a const iterator, you're trying to convert it to a non-const one and that is not legal.

Comment: In C++11, write `for (int e : sequence) { std::cout << e << " "; }`.

Comment: @juanchopanza I think the question is slightly different (OP already identified the problem being about `const`) where an answer here would be about the `vector` interface preventing changes to the underlying content.

Answer (score 4):

You need a `const_iterator`, change the for loop as follows:

```
for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator it = sequence.begin() ;
       it != sequence.end() ;    ++it)
```

If you have C++11 compiler, you can simplify it using `auto`

```
for (auto it = sequence.begin() ;
           it != sequence.end() ;  ++it)
```

Or you can use range for range loop available with c++11

```
for (auto & val: sequence)
 {
    std::cout << val << " ";
 }
```

Comment: Or better yet, `auto`